# Why is my Passport auth function not executing when called within a route?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm using Passport to protect the front and back end of a MEAN stack app. The app is structured like so:

```
monstermash
    config // server configuration
    public // static directory that will serve the entire Angular frontend
    app
        index.js // initialization of the server
        models 
            index.js // mongoose schemas and models
        passport 
            index.js // configuration for passport and all my strategies
        routes 
            index.js // basic route definitions for the API (using functions defined under v1, below) and UI (routes defined inline here for simplicity's sake)
                v1
                    index.js // all the functions called to power the API routes
```

Here's `app/index.js` since I know it's sometimes a matter of calling application middleware in the right order:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();
var CONFIG = require('config').BASE;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var models = require('./models');

app.passport = require('./passport');
app.port = CONFIG.PORT;
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
})); 
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ 
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

var routes = require('./routes');

app.use(express.static('public', {redirect:false}));
routes(app)

module.exports = app
```

`passport/index.js` looks like this. A lot of the commented-out bits are only cut out in an effort to get this down to bare bones for debugging:

```
var models = require('../models')

passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
  , LocalAPIKeyStrategy = require('passport-localapikey-update').Strategy;

passport.use('localapikey', new LocalAPIKeyStrategy(
  {apiKeyHeader:'x-auth-token'},
  function(apikey, done) {
  console.log('api key');
    models.User.findOne({ apikey: apikey }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(
  function (req, username, password, done) {
    console.log('trying local');
    models.User.findOne({
      local: {username: username}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          console.log('no user');
          return done (null, false);
        }

        if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
          console.log('bad pwd');
          return done(null, false);
        }
        return done (null, user);
      }
    })
  }
));

module.exports = passport;
```

The localaipkey strategy is included here just to illustrate that *it* works and is configured in much the same way as the local-signup one.

Then my `routes/index.js` looks like this. HTML for login forms is inline here because this is just a perliminary test. Note that I'm not doing anything other than checking validation. Including one of the API routes here too do demonstrate how that's set up. The UI code here is lifted straight from a Passport tutorial, since I went back to the drawing board and got rid of my own code on the matter.

```
var v1 = require('./v1');

  // API routes as an example. This authentication is called before the route and works fine.

  module.exports = function(app) {
    /* API: V1 */
    app.route('/v1/monster/:id')
      .put(
        app.passport.authenticate('localapikey', { session: false }),
        v1.monster.update)
      .delete(
        app.passport.authenticate('localapikey', { session: false }),
        v1.monster.delete
      );

    // My test login routes. Here, authenticate is called inside the route because it's the handler for logging in.

    app.route('/login')
      .post(
        function (req, res) {
          console.log(req.body);
          app.passport.authenticate('local-signup', { 
            successRedirect: '/root',
            failureRedirect: '/fail'
          });
      })
      .get(function (req,res) {
        res.send('<!-- views/login.ejs -->\
          <!doctype html>\
          <html>\
          <head>\
              <title>Node Authentication</title>\
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- load bootstrap css -->\
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- load fontawesome -->\
              <style>\
                  body        { padding-top:80px; }\
              </style>\
          </head>\
          <body>\
          <div class="container">\
          \
          <form action="/login" method="post">\
            <div>\
                <label>Username:</label>\
                <input type="text" name="username"/>\
            </div>\
            <div>\
                <label>Password:</label>\
                <input type="password" name="password"/>\
            </div>\
            <div>\
                <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>\
            </div>\
        </form>\
          \
          </div>\
          </body>\
          </html>');
      });
```

So that form submits a `POST:/login` request with the form data. The form body is there in `req.body` but the `console.log` messages I have in the validation function never get logged. The form submission just hangs and hangs; there's no `res.send()` on that route because the authentication should either pass or fail and never get to that, but the whole `app.passport.authenticate()` function is just totally bypassed.

I've done a lot of trial-and-error on this, and I've found that if I call `app.passport.authenticate()` with the name of a strategy that isn't even registered, the same thing happens: there's no failure message, it just continues on with the route like it wasn't even there. So *maybe* the issue is that this is happening and it's not recognizing the `local-signup` strategy being registered, though I don't know why that would be and the `localapikey` strategy is found.

Side note, I actually am testing this with a `username` and `password` set in the form; I found one SO question on that from someone who was trying empty or passwordless submissions and not seeing their validation function execute, so I'm sure it's not that.

Comment: Further digging indicates two things: 

One, that the `passReqToCallback` option in `app.passport.authenticate` seems to be defaulting to `true` instead of `false`, so my verification function is called wrong and it should be `function (req, username, password, done)`

Two, that `app.passport.authenticate()` works just fine when it's called before the route function, but seems to be totally skipped when called inside.

I think these might be related, since previously the whole reason to put it inside the route was to give it access to `req`. I'm starting to think the docs are outdated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the answer to my question is basically "because you can't call the authenticate function inside a route."

I'm not deleting the question because I know that I got that idea from some Passport tutorial somewhere, therefore someone else may fall prey to the same thing later.

Comment: If for some reason the specified fields are empty "". The function would not be called. It may be a bug or by design.